# Extracting significance of gam smoothing terms

Tags: generalized-additive-model, splines, mgcv

I have a time course data to which I'd like to fit a `gam` and have easy interpretability, and by that I mean obtaining `coefficient` estimates for each of the `spline`s.

These are my data:

```
df <- data.frame(y = c(0.15,0.17,0.07,0.17,0.01,0.15,0.18,0.04,-0.06,-0.08,0,0.03,-0.27,-0.93,0.04,0.12,0.08,0.15,0.04,0.15,0.03,0.09,0.11,0.13,-0.11,-0.32,-0.7,-0.78,0.07,0.04,0.06,0.12,-0.15,0.05,-0.08,0.14,-0.02,-0.14,-0.24,-0.32,-0.78,-0.81,-0.04,-0.25,-0.09,0.02,-0.13,-0.2,-0.04,0,0.02,-0.05,-0.19,-0.37,-0.57,-0.81),
                 log2.time = rep(c(-1, 0, 1, 1.58,2, 2.58, 3, 3.32, 3.58, 4.17, 4.58, 5.58, 6.17, 7.39),4))
```

I thought I'd use the `mgcv` `R` `package`, using this model:

```
fit <- mgcv::gam(y ~ s(log2.time), data = df, method = "REML")
```

Using `summary(fit)`, I get:

```
> summary(fit)

Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
y ~ s(log2.time)

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -0.10893    0.01681  -6.479 3.65e-08 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
               edf Ref.df     F p-value    
s(log2.time) 4.101  5.036 46.36  <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.809   Deviance explained = 82.3%
-REML = -27.673  Scale est. = 0.015829  n = 56
```

So, overall the `log2.time` smoothing term is significantly different from zero. But as stated above I would like to obtain a `coefficient` for each of the `spline`s, along with their standard errors and a measure of whether they are significantly different from zero.

Should I be using `cubic splines` for this purpose, with this model:

```
fit <- mgcv::gam(y ~ s(log2.time,bs='cr'), data = df, method = "REML")
```

And can the `spline` `coefficient` estimates be obtained as follows:

```
spline.coefs <- coef(fit)[-1]
spline.knots <- fit$smooth[[1]]$xp

for(s in 2:length(spline.knots)){
  spline.coefs[s-1] <- spline.coefs[s-1]/(spline.knots[s]-spline.knots[s-1])
}
```

And then would the `coefficient` standard errors be:

```
spline.coefs.se <- sqrt(diag(vcov(fit, unconditional  = TRUE)))[-1]
```

And finally, can p-values for the spline `coefficient` estimates be obtained?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The diagonal of the variance matrix of the model parameters contains the variances of all the coefficients. If you take the square root of the diagonal elements you'll get the standard errors of the intercept plus the spline coefficients:

```
> fit <- mgcv::gam(y ~ s(log2.time,k=3), data = df, method = "REML")
> vcov(fit)
                 (Intercept) s(log2.time).1 s(log2.time).2
(Intercept)     3.122736e-04  -1.059763e-18  -3.707237e-20
s(log2.time).1 -1.059763e-18   3.968441e-03   3.479426e-08
s(log2.time).2 -3.707237e-20   3.479426e-08   3.122736e-04
> sqrt(diag(vcov(fit)))
   (Intercept) s(log2.time).1 s(log2.time).2 
    0.01767127     0.06299556     0.01767127
```

If you use `vcov(fit, unconditional  = TRUE)` you'll get a (Bayesian) covariance matrix adjusted for having estimated the smoothness parameter, $\lambda$. Without this, the uncertainty on the spline coefficients is too small as it assumes $\lambda$ is known.

The values shown by `coef(fit)` are the parameters for the two thin plate spline basis functions used in the model. They are not the slopes of the fitted spline itself however; the slope or first derivative of the spline is varying throughout the range of $x$. You can estimate the slope of the spline at any point using finite differences if you want that, and compute a confidence interval on that slope.

There is only **one** spline here, built up from **two** basis functions (well three depending on how you look at it, but one of those is the intercept). Your use of "spline" and "slope" are a little confusing — if you care to clarify I will update this answer should elements of it be irrelevant or lacking.

Note that your model was actually fitted using `k = 3` and then the constant basis function was dropped, hence a maximum of 2 degrees of freedom for the smoother. However even this has been penalized a little; if you don't want penalization (smoothness selection, or estimation of $\lambda$), use `fx = TRUE`.

### Update:

If you want piecewise-linear fits then you can achieve this with the b-spline basis `bs = 'bs'`:

```
fit <- mgcv::gam(y ~ s(log2.time, bs='bs', k = 3, m = 1), data = df, 
                 method = "REML")
```

where `m = 1` now refers to the *order* of the spline, not the penalty. In this model the hinge point of the fit is in the middle of the data. Removing the `k = 3` results in the default fit with `k = 10`.

The coefficients are still not the slopes of the linear sections however. You should be able to extract the derivative of the spline from the b-spline basis but I haven't worked out how to coax **mgcv** into yielding that info just yet. However, you can get this with finite differences.

```
library('mgcv')
devtools::install_github('gavinsimpson/gratia')
library('gratia') # for finite differences-based derivatives
library('ggplot2')
library('cowplot')
theme_set(theme_bw())

## fit piecewise-linear model
fit <- gam(y ~ s(log2.time, bs='bs', m = 1), data = df, 
           method = "REML")
## new locations to evaluate everything at
newdf <- with(df, data.frame(log2.time = seq(min(log2.time), 
                                             max(log2.time),
                                             length = 100)))
## extract model coefs
b <- coef(fit)
## get the Xp matrix, the prediction matrix for the spline
Xp <- predict(fit, newdf, type = "lpmatrix")
## evaluate 1st derivative at new locations
d <- fderiv(fit, newdata = newdf)

## stick everything together
pltdf <- data.frame(log2.time  = newdf$log2.time,
                    spline     = Xp[,-1] %*% b[-1],
                    derivative = d[[1]][['s(log2.time)']][['deriv']])

## individual plots
p1 <- ggplot(pltdf, aes(x = log2.time, y = spline)) +
    geom_line()
p2 <- ggplot(pltdf, aes(x = log2.time, y = derivative)) +
    geom_step()
## combine
plot_grid(p1, p2, align = 'hv', axis = 'lrtb', ncol = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gavin Simpson. I've updated my post to better reflect what I'm after. Hope it makes it easier to address.

Comment: @dan what do you mean by a "spline slope"?

Comment: I meant spline coefficient. Sorry about that - bad use of term. Post is updated.

Comment: @dan that `for` loop is doing something very odd. It looks like you are trying to estimate the rate of change between knots but doing that using the estimated coefficient for the basis function. Are you thinking of this model as fitting a piece-wise linear model? Anyway, `coef()` already gives you the model coefficients, you don't need to compute them. And the SEs I mentioned are for the things returned by `coef()` not the thing you are computing. I'll try to dig out code to plot the basis functions being used in this model as the coefs correspond to those basis functions.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gavin Simpson. I think that perhaps a piecewise linear spline regression, perhaps optimizing the location of knots, might better address my needs in this problem. Perhaps the `MARS` algorithm (implemented in the `earth` `R` `package`), might work well here. So perhaps it's not worth your time bothering with looking for code that plots the basis function.

Comment: @dan you can do piecewise linear fits in mgcv using the b-spline basis. I've added an example of achieving this. MARS may be the way to go here --- a bit of overkill as it is supposed to be used with a large number of predictor variables. I guess it would work and it would select the knot location for you. The code I showed in the update will compute the derivatives for your original `fit` with a low-rank cubic spline (but you won't want `geom_step()` for `p2`; use `geom_line()` instead) if you want to see the derivatives of that much smoother model, even with `k = 3`.